# Boot on USB from a previous version of OSX

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, startup, bootable-disk

I own a mid-2013 Macbook Air running Mavericks and wish to boot on a USB stick containing a bootable version of DiskWarrior. The problem is DiskWarrior wasn't updated for quite some time and, though the application version works just fine in Mavericks, the bootable version is old and is based on OSX 10.6.7.

My usb disk is detected correctly as a startup disk inside Mavericks, and I can even see it as an option when I press ALT during startup. The problem is selecting this disk just show the Apple logo and the actual boot from the usb never takes place. I recall reading someday about how OSX would prevent you from booting from older version of the system. Is this what's happening here? Is there anyway around this? Do I absolutely have to find an older mac that would allow me to boot from OSX 10.6.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't boot a version of OS X older than the version of OS X that shipped with the machine. This is because older versions of OS X do not contain the drivers required to support the newer hardware that it had no knowledge of at the time of development. The boot sequence will freeze on the Apple logo or blue screen and you will not be able to boot.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, the problem isn't that Mavericks prevents me from booting, it's that OSX 10.6.7 detects hardware unknown to it and just stops booting? So this really is a dead end and I have no choice but find a working mac that was sold with 10.6.7 or an older version of OSX is that it? Would trying to boot from the usb stick on a Windows PC result in any good?

Answer (score 1):

Just to keep this answer up to date…

[DiskWarrior 5](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/index.html) is now available, as a paid upgrade.

> DiskWarrior 5 supports any locally connected Mac OS Standard (HFS) or Mac OS Extended (HFS Plus) disk including Fusion Drives, RAID volumes, journaled disks, case-sensitive disks, FileVaults and Time Machine backups. DiskWarrior 5 supports both PowerPC and Intel Macs started in OS X 10.5.8 through 10.10.
>
> Startup Disk Repair Requirements
>   DiskWarrior now ships on a bootable flash drive instead of DVD. If you plan to rebuild the directory of your startup (built-in) disk, you need to start up from another disk capable of starting up in OS X 10.5.8 through 10.10, such as the DiskWarrior Recovery flash drive or your Mac's OS X Recovery (the Recovery HD). OS X Recovery is available in OS X 10.7 (Lion) and later.
>
> The DiskWarrior Recovery flash drive ships with the ability to start up any Intel Mac that originally came with OS X 10.4, 10.5 or 10.6 installed. If you have a newer Intel Mac, you can use the included DiskWarrior Recovery Maker to update the DiskWarrior Recovery flash drive to start up your newer Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of DiskWarrior are you using? On the [support](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/support.html) page of the website it mentions the following:

> **10/22/2013 - DiskWarrior 4 version 4.4 Compatible with OS X 10.9 Mavericks**
>   The previously released DiskWarrior 4 version 4.4 is required to run an installed copy of DiskWarrior while started from 10.9 Mavericks. If you haven't already done so, you can use the [free updater](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/diskwarriorupdate.html) for existing owners of DiskWarrior 4 versions 4.0-4.3.

Comment: *"though the application version works just fine in Mavericks, the **bootable version is old** and is based on OS X 10.6.7"*

Comment: Exactly, I looked around and it seems there isn't any recent bootable version of it.